# Unpacking nested json into df

Tags: python

```
def parse_data(shots):
  all_events = []
  for s in shots:
    print(json.dumps(s, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
    attributes = {
        "possession": s['possession'],
        "possession_team": s['possession_team']['name'],
        "play_pattern": s['play_pattern']['name'],
        "formation": s['tactics']['formation'],
        "player_name": s['tactics']['lineup']['player']['name'],
        "player_position": s['tactics']['lineup']['position']['name']
    }
    all_events.append(attributes)
  return pd.DataFrame(all_events)
```

s:

```
   {
        "id": "2125b764-3f89-41e9-b017-cc954452f533",
        "index": 3478,
        "minute": 84,
        "period": 2,
        "play_pattern": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "From Free Kick"
        },
        "possession": 186,
        "possession_team": {
            "id": 796,
            "name": "Russia"
        },
        "second": 54,
        "tactics": {
            "formation": 3421,
            "lineup": [
                {
                    "jersey_number": 16,
                    "player": {
                        "id": 21298,
                        "name": "Matvey Safonov"
                    },
                    "position": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Goalkeeper"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "jersey_number": 8,
                    "player": {
                        "id": 18735,
                        "name": "Dmitriy Barinov"
                    },
                    "position": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Right Center Back"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "jersey_number": 9,
                    "player": {
                        "id": 38178,
                        "name": "Aleksandr Sobolev"
                    },
                    "position": {
                        "id": 23,
                        "name": "Center Forward"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "timestamp": "00:39:54.909"
    }
```

The function works except when trying to retrieve the values for "player_name" and "player_position". I am hoping to output a df that looks like:

| possession | possession_team | play_pattern | formation | player_name | player_position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 186 | Russia | From Free Kick | 3421 | Matvey Safonov | Goalkeeper |
| 186 | Russia | From Free Kick | 3421 | Dmitriy Barinov | Right Center Back |
| 186 | Russia | From Free Kick | 3421 | Aleksandr Sobolev | Center Forward |

How can I achieve this using my current function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an inner loop on the `tactics/lineup` array:

```py
def parse_data(shots):
  all_events = []
  for s in shots:
    print(json.dumps(s, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
    for l in s['tactics']['lineup']:
        attributes = {
            "possession": s['possession'],
            "possession_team": s['possession_team']['name'],
            "play_pattern": s['play_pattern']['name'],
            "formation": s['tactics']['formation'],
            "player_name": l['player']['name'],
            "player_position": l['position']['name']
        }
        all_events.append(attributes)
    return pd.DataFrame(all_events)
```

This will add an entry to `all_events` for each player in the lineup. For your sample `s` value, the result will be:

```
   possession possession_team    play_pattern  formation        player_name    player_position
0         186          Russia  From Free Kick       3421     Matvey Safonov         Goalkeeper
1         186          Russia  From Free Kick       3421    Dmitriy Barinov  Right Center Back
2         186          Russia  From Free Kick       3421  Aleksandr Sobolev     Center Forward
```